# GraphQL unable to get query working

Tags: graphql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have two tables categories & subcategories defined as

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
`image` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE `sub_categories` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`cat` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`type` int(11) NOT NULL,
)
```

Here **cat** field in **sub_categories** table is foreign key to **id** in **categories** table

GraphQL schema is defined as

```
export const schema = `
type Category {
id:    ID
name: String
image: String
subcategories : [SubCategory]
}`
```

AND

```
type SubCategory {
id:    ID
name: String
cat: Int
type: Int
}
```

Also my DB model in Bookshelf.js is as

```
const Category = db.Model.extend({
tableName: 'categories',
subcats: function () {
return this.hasMany(SubCategory,"cat");
}
})
```

My GraphQL query is as

```
async getAllCategories() {
const allCats = await Category
  .fetchAll()
  .then(cats => {
    return cats.toJSON()
  })
return allCats
```

}

Now when I call

```
{
 getAllCategories {
  id
  name
  subcategories {
   id
   name
  }
 }
}
```

I am getting response as

```
{
"data": {
"getAllCategories": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "usa",
    "subcategories": null
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "japan",
    "subcategories": null
  },
 ]
 }
}
```

Here subcategories field is null where as I would like to get all subcategories in a particular category connected by the foreign key cat in sub_categories table.

Comment: How did you get Bookshelf to work with GraphQL in the first place?

Comment: hi i followed [this guide](https://expertise.jetruby.com/our-experience-with-node-js-react-graphql-c40007ad4373)

Answer (score 0):

You have to eager load the sub-categories since it's not automatic:

```
const allCats = await Category
  .fetchAll({withRelated: 'subcats'})
  .then(cats => {
    return cats.toJSON()
  })
```

Comment: still getting the same error. is there anyway to show the final sql query build in this code? would i have to take each id from category table and loop over sub_categories table?

Comment: What error? You only mentioned that there were no sub-categories. You can pass the `debug: true` option to `fetchAll`: `.fetchAll({withRelated: 'subcats', debug: true})` to see the generated SQL.